# How to prevent the jump during css transition?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, css-transitions

I'm developing a "stack" component, which is inspired by [ElastiStack](http://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticStack/).

[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/yeVBwN). The demo works fine on desktop Chrome. But the transition is not working in my iOS Safari. I extracted a [small snippet](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/NxbdWZ) and found that there will be a jump in space when animation begins and ends. The jump happens in desktop Chrome as well as iOS Safari.

So the reason why the transition of my stack is not working on iOS Safari is that you can only see the jump but the transition. As long as you extend the transition time from `.3s` to `1s`, you'll see the jump at the beginning, the transition, and the jump at the end.

Why is there a jump at the beginning and end? How to prevent it, making the transition smoother?

---

Update:
Thanks @vals. The snippet's jumping effect is resulted from my mistake -- I changed the `transform` css on `div`s rather than `.stack-pane`. The snippet's bug is fixed.

But still, I don't know how to prevent the jump on iOS Safari in my stack demo.

[This snippet](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/OMbbGr) could better illustrate my problem. Please try it on iOS Safari.

It turns out that on iOS Safari, an unexpected jump will happen at the END of transition.

---

Update: It's very weird that, after a dinner, the smooth transition is back to my iOS Safari... My WeChat crashed during dinner, and I reopened it. The transition becomes smooth. So maybe it's simple because my iPhone was sluggish when I was testing the snippets.

Comment: @CodeiSir, [the snippet](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/NxbdWZ) can also reproduce the jump on my desktop chrome. I prefer css-transition to css-animation because it's easier to be configured (transition time, opacity, etc), to `jquery animate` because `jquery animate` cannot animate `transform` easily (have to use step) and I am concerned about the efficiency of animating many stack-pane using `jquery animate`.
I wonder if the jump is because animating `translate3d` is slow in browsers. Let me do some experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are transforming "div"s, so you are applying the change both to .stack and .stackpane.

But only .stackpane has a transition set.

So, the change to .stack (that probably is unwanted) is done suddenly

Comment: Ah, you're right. The `stack` related classes are added after my js code. My fault to make this stupid mistake..

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZbWQM

The problem was that `i + 1` in

```
$(this).css({
    transform: 'translate3d(' + (-50 * (i + 0)) + 'px, 0, ' + (50 * (i + 0)) + 'px)'
});
```

Wich made it jump ahead